# destructuring javascript - nicer write

Tags: javascript

I have such an array and the same id is always repeated in objects:

```
const array =    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "test",
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "test2",
        }
    ]
```

and I would like to assign id to the variable, but I would like to do it nicer than:

```
const { id } = array[0];
```

how to do it? and is it possible?

Comment: `const [{ id }] = array;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and I would like to assign id to the variable

There are two `id`s in that example. Your version is fine, but you can also use array destructuring on top of the object destructuring:

```
const [{id}] = array; // For the first one
//or
const [, {id}] = array; // For the second one
```

```js
const array =    [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "test",
    },
    {
        id: 2, // *** Note I changed it
        name: "test2",
    }
];

{
    const [{id}] = array;
    console.log("First one:", id);
}
{
    const [, {id}] = array;
    console.log("Second one:", id);
}
```

If you want to grab it from an arbitrary index, rather than a bunch of commas (like `const [, , , , , {id}] =...`), you can use object destructuring (since arrays are objects):

```
const {23: {id}} = array; // Same as const {id} = array[23];
```

```js
const array = Array.from({length: 24}, (_, i) => ({id: i + 1, name: `Test ${i + 1}`}));

const {23: {id}} = array; // Same as const {id} = array[23];
console.log("At index 23:", id);
```